# How to move tf binary to another location?

Tags: linux, terraform

I installed an older version of terraform and the binary is in my downloads, how do I move it to another location? have to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tfenv/3.0.0/versions/1.0.0/terraform

I used the method here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli

but I get: terraform is not a directory

Answer (score 2):

think about using [tfenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv) if you want to maintain different terraform versions in same PC.

Comment: yes I installed it, but then unintstalled the tf and installed an older version, now I am having trouble activating it, hence the question.

Comment: I have installed terraform older version but I can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

By your path, it seems that you are using homebrew as a package manager.

Use these steps to install any version of terraform.

- **Install [`tfenv`](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv)**

```bash
brew install tfenv
```

- **List the available versions of `terraform` via `tfenv`** (optional)

```bash
## To view all the available versions via tfenv.
 tfenv list-remote 

## tfenv list-remote | head -n <number_of_last_terraform_versions_you_want_to_list>
 tfenv list-remote | head -n 20 ## example
```

- **To Install the required `terraform` version via `tfenv`**

```bash
## tfenv install <terraform_version_you_want>
tfenv install 1.3.7
```

- **Switch to the version you installed via `tfenv` in the past or the last step.**

```bash
## tfenv use <terraform_version_you_want>
tfenv use 1.3.7
```

Comment: correct, this is what I have done, however, the Terraform is not installed or active, when I try to run any tf command I get zsh: command not found: terraform